# What are the differences between simulated annealing and genetic algorithms?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, simulated-annealing, constraint-satisfaction

What are the relevant differences, in terms of performance and use cases, between simulated annealing (with bean search) and genetic algorithms?

I know that SA can be thought as GA where the population size is only one, but I don't know the key difference between the two.

Also, I am trying to think of a situation where SA will outperform GA or GA will outperform SA. Just one simple example which will help me understand will be enough.

Comment: "SA can be thought as GA where the population size is only one"- Not exactly.  Though simulated annealing maintains only 1 solution from one trial to the next, its acceptance of worse-performing candidates is much more integral to its function that the same thing would be in a genetic algorithm.  In fact, some GAs only ever accept improving candidates.  Also, realize that one "generation" for SA typically is much faster in real time than the same for a GA, so more generations may be tried in the same time- an important practical consideration.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Well strictly speaking, these two things--**simulated annealing** (SA) and **genetic algorithms** are neither algorithms nor is their purpose 'data mining'.

Both are *meta-heuristics*--a couple of levels above 'algorithm' on the abstraction scale. In other words, both terms refer to high-level metaphors--one borrowed from metallurgy and the other from evolutionary biology. In the meta-heuristic taxonomy, SA is a *single-state method* and GA is a *population method* (in a sub-class along with PSO, ACO, et al, usually referred to as *biologically-inspired meta-heuristics*).

These two meta-heuristics are used to solve optimization problems, particularly (though not exclusively) in *combinatorial optimization* (aka *constraint-satisfaction programming*). Combinatorial optimization refers to optimization by selecting from among a set of discrete items--in other words, there is no continuous function to minimize. The knapsack problem, traveling salesman problem, cutting stock problem--are all combinatorial optimization problems.

The connection to data mining is that the core of many (most?) supervised Machine Learning (ML) algorithms is the solution of an optimization problem--(Multi-Layer Perceptron and Support Vector Machines for instance).

Any solution technique to solve cap problems, regardless of the algorithm, will consist essentially of these steps (which are typically coded as a single block within a recursive loop):

1. encode the domain-specific details
   in a cost function (it's the
   step-wise minimization of the value
   returned from this function that
   constitutes a 'solution' to the c/o
   problem);
2. evaluate the cost function passing
   in an initial 'guess' (to begin
   iteration);
3. based on the value returned from the
   cost function, generate a subsequent
   candidate solution (or more than
   one, depending on the
   meta-heuristic) to the cost
   function;
4. evaluate each candidate solution by
   passing it in an argument set, to
   the cost function;
5. repeat steps (iii) and (iv) until
   either some convergence criterion is
   satisfied or a maximum number of
   iterations is reached.

Meta-heuristics are directed to step (iii) above; hence, SA and GA differ in how they generate candidate solutions for evaluation by the cost function. In other words, that's the place to look to understand how these two meta-heuristics differ.

Informally, the essence of an algorithm directed to solution of combinatorial optimization is how it handles a candidate solution whose value returned from the cost function is ***worse*** than the current best candidate solution (the one that returns the lowest value from the cost function). The simplest way for an optimization algorithm to handle such a candidate solution is to reject it outright--that's what the hill climbing algorithm does. But by doing this, simple hill climbing will always miss a better solution separated from the current solution by a hill. Put another way, a sophisticated optimization algorithm has to include a technique for (temporarily) accepting a candidate solution worse than (i.e., uphill from) the current best solution because an even better solution than the current one might lie along a path through that worse solution.

---

So how do SA and GA generate candidate solutions?

The essence of SA is usually expressed in terms of the probability that a higher-cost candidate solution will be accepted (the entire expression inside the double parenthesis is an exponent:

```
p = e((-highCost - lowCost)/temperature)
```

Or in python:

```
p = pow(math.e, (-hiCost - loCost) / T)
```

The 'temperature' term is a variable whose value decays during progress of the optimization--and therefore, the probability that SA will accept a worse solution decreases as iteration number increases.

Put another way, when the algorithm begins iterating, T is very large, which as you can see, causes the algorithm to move to every newly created candidate solution, whether better or worse than the current best solution--i.e., it is doing a *random walk* in the solution space. As iteration number increases (i.e., as the temperature cools) the algorithm's search of the solution space becomes less permissive, until at T = 0, the behavior is identical to a simple hill-climbing algorithm (i.e., only solutions better than the current best solution are accepted).

***Genetic Algorithms*** are very different. For one thing--and this is a big thing--it generates not a single candidate solution but an entire 'population of them'. It works like this: GA calls the cost function on each member (candidate solution) of the population. It then ranks them, from best to worse, ordered by the value returned from the cost function ('best' has the lowest value). From these ranked values (and their corresponding candidate solutions) the next population is created. New members of the population are created in essentially one of three ways. The first is usually referred to as 'elitism' and in practice usually refers to just taking the highest ranked candidate solutions and passing them straight through--unmodified--to the next generation. The other two ways that new members of the population are usually referred to as 'mutation' and 'crossover'. Mutation usually involves a change in one element in a candidate solution vector from the current population to create a solution vector in the new population, e.g., [4, 5, 1, 0, 2] => [4, 5, 2, 0, 2]. The result of the crossover operation is like what would happen if vectors could have sex--i.e., a new child vector whose elements are comprised of some from each of two parents.

So those are the algorithmic differences between GA and SA. What about the differences in performance?

In practice: (my observations are limited to combinatorial optimization problems) GA nearly always beats SA (returns a lower 'best' return value from the cost function--ie, a value close to the solution space's global minimum), but at a higher computation cost. As far as i am aware, the textbooks and technical publications recite the same conclusion on resolution.

but here's the thing: GA is inherently parallelizable; what's more, it's trivial to do so because the individual "search agents" comprising each population do not need to exchange messages--ie, they work independently of each other. Obviously that means *GA computation can be distributed*, which means **in practice, you can get much better results (closer to the global minimum) and better performance (execution speed).**

In what circumstances might SA outperform GA? The general scenario i think would be those optimization problems having a small solution space so that the result from SA and GA are practically the same, yet the execution context (e.g., hundreds of similar problems run in batch mode) favors the faster algorithm (which should always be SA).

Comment: Great work.What about SA with beam search,are there any differences?

Comment: well, SA w/ local beam search versus GA has the same set of differences as ordinary SA versus GA *except that* SA w/ local beam is like GA in that it considers simultaneously a *set* of candidate solutions ('states') rather than just one.

Comment: Why do you say 'recursive function'? I don't see any need for recursion.

Comment: " The result of the crossover operation is like what would happen if vectors could have sex"

Answer (score 6):

It is really difficult to compare the two since they were inspired from different domains..

A Genetic Algorithm maintains a population of possible solutions, and at each step, selects pairs of possible solution, combines them (crossover), and applies some random changes (mutation). The algorithm is based the idea of "survival of the fittest" where the selection process is done according to a fitness criteria (usually in optimization problems it is simply the value of the objective function evaluated using the current solution). The crossover is done in hope that two good solutions, when combined, might give even better solution.

On the other hand, Simulated Annealing only tracks one solution in the space of possible solutions, and at each iteration considers whether to move to a neighboring solution or stay in the current one according to some probabilities (which decays over time). This is different from a heuristic search (say greedy search) in that it doesn't suffer from the problems of local optimum since it can get unstuck from cases where all neighboring solutions are worst the current one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm far from an expert on these algorithms, but I'll try and help out.

I think the biggest difference between the two is the idea of crossover in GA and so any example of a learning task that is better suited to GA than SA is going to hinge on what crossover means in that situation and how it is implemented.

The idea of crossover is that you can meaningfully combine two solutions to produce a better one. I think this only makes sense if the solutions to a problem are structured in some way. I could imagine, for example, in multi-class classification taking two (or many) classifiers that are good at classifying a particular class and combining them by voting to make a much better classifier. Another example might be [Genetic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming), where the solution can be expressed as a tree, but I find it hard to come up with a good example where you could combine two programs to create a better one.

I think it's difficult to come up with a compelling case for one over the other because they really are quite similar algorithms, perhaps having been developed from very different starting points.

Comment: Thanks Stomp,is it the case that in SA we will only have mutation,while in GA,we will have both mutation and combination?

Comment: Yeah, SA is a lot like GA only without crossover.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Comment: You can actually have a functional GA without the crossover element (only mutation). The only difference with SA then is that you have multiple solutions. Also, a GA usually improves ifs efficiency when the mutation chance is gradually lowered when reaching better solutions, just like in SA. Such a GA could be seen as a sort of 'multi'-SA.